# POP3 Transmission Process

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, email, pop3

I was wondering if anyone could help me out (not with code, although that would be appreciated), with the logic behind checking and retrieving messages from a POP3 mail server.

I.e.

```
Establish connection
Validate credentials
Enumerate message list
Check each message to see if it's "new"
Download "new" message(s).
```

Would this be the correct way about doing this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way of looking at something like this is to have a look what something else does.  Run Wireshark or some other packet capture software, and use an e-mail client to check.  Anyway, the basics of a POP3 session are as follows:

```
USER username
PASS password
LIST                <-- Shows the size of each waiting message
UIDL                <-- Shows a unique ID for each waiting message
RETR 1              <-- Retrieves message with index 1
DELE 1              <-- Deletes the message you just retrieved
QUIT
```

The first char of all of the responses except RETR will be a + (success) or a - (failure).

If you are deleting messages off the server after retrieving them, you don't need to bother with UIDL.  If you are leaving them, you can use UIDL to get a unique ID for each message which you store locally to show you have retrieved that message before.

For more details, see the [RFC](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1939.html).  [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POP3) also lists a more in depth example, showing the server response.

Answer (score 1):

These should be useful:

- [POP3 Email Client (.NET 2.0)](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/Pop3MailClient.aspx)
- [POP3 Client as a C# Class](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/despop3client.aspx)
- [Retrieve Mail From a POP3 Server Using C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/popapp.aspx)
- [POP3 Sequence Diagram](https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://www.eventhelix.com/realtimemantra/networking/POP3.pdf)
- [POP3 Reference](http://www.pnambic.com/Goodies/POP3Ref.html)

Comment: Thank you. I have tried many other components which never worked. So I thought my best bet would be to understand how it is done and roll out my own implementation. Great links, thanks!